# Posting CSRF Token with multiple tokens?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, csrf

I have been attempting to scrape a website with a login (using yelp).  First question for better understanding: I followed a few tutorials to get the ideas, and noticed they all make dictionaries with the CSRF tokens, however, when I scrape the yelp login site, I find 6 tokens.  I know that I can't have a duplicate key in a dictionary, so is the tutorial's using dictionaries for this redundant/incorrect since I will only end up with the last token?

Secondly, if there are multiple tokens, which do you use? Or how do you use all of them?  I can't seem to get the login to work and have read the documentation for BeautifulSoup and Requests, and scoured Stack the last night.  Code below. 
Thanks for any explanations.

```
s = requests.session()
login = s.get('https://www.yelp.com/login')

soup = BeautifulSoup(login.text, 'html.parser')
tokenList = soup.find_all(type = 'hidden', attrs={"name": "csrftok"})
c = login.cookies  #Just peeked into cookies to see if there is a token 
print(c)

keys = [x.attrs["name"] for x in tokenList]
values = [x.attrs["value"] for x in tokenList]
#If I print these two lists, I get 6 keys of the "csrftok" String, and 6 
#different keys.  

email = "my email"
password = "my password"
#I tried creating a dictionary with zip of all the tokens, etc. This 
#is an attempt just using the first key and value I find.
d = {'email': email, 'password': password, keys[0]: values[0]}
response = s.post('https://www.yelp.com/login', data = d)

print(response.url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried like this? I think it should lead you to the right direction:

```
s = requests.session()
login = s.get('https://www.yelp.com/login')

soup = BeautifulSoup(login.text, 'lxml')
token = soup.select(".csrftok")[0]['value']

email = "my email"
password = "my password"

headers={
'accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
'referer':'https://www.yelp.com/login',
'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
'x-distil-ajax':'fytrybseesxsvsresb',
'x-requested-with':'XMLHttpRequest'
}

payload = {
'csrftok':token,
'email':email,
'password':password,
}

response = s.post('https://www.yelp.com/login/newajax', data = payload, headers=headers)
print(response.url)
```

Comment: Forgot to add the `headers`. Fixed it already. There is no way for me to check it. However, let me know.

Comment: Ok, so I get a valid status response now, however, if printing the response.url, it should return the new url after login, correct?  I don't believe it is logging in, otherwise I should be able to search for my name, for example in the text and return a boolean?  Also, I'm assuming newajax is your location and should be removed from my own code?

Comment: What did you see when you print `response.text` or `response.json()` as the response is supposed to be in json? I can't check out. Btw, I assume you set your request parameters derived from `chrome/firefox developer tools`. If you didn't do exactly the way I surmised then the parameters i used above should be right.

Comment: Ok, so I realized newajax was a command, not a location.  I arrive at the Captcha text now.  Your assumption on the parameters was correct also.  I suppose I will just let it rest for now until the Captcha goes away.   Thank you!  Also, is there any particular reason why it had to be parsed in xml and not html?

Comment: Html.parser is okay. However, i will give you a link to clarify why i chose lxml. On a mobile device now.

Comment: When you are on that page, scroll down a little to find a table in which you can notice the different between parsers. Link to that table: [Link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) .If you track down this link you will find details about merits and demerits of different parsers: [Ano_link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)